# Update library version number using Script API

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform

My ultimate goal is to be able to update the library version number included in a bunch of bound google apps scripts.  The code below is a simplified version that only gets the contents of the script as a JSON.  I'm having trouble accessing the values of a key that points to an object.  For simplicity, the code is only trying to extract the time zone which isn't as nested as the library version number.

To run the code you need to include the two scopes commented in the script below and create a cloud platform project that has the Script API enabled. Then add the project number for the GCP you created under Resources->Cloud Platform project.

```
function getScriptData() {
  //scopes needed for this script
  //https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.projects
  //https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request

  var scriptID = ScriptApp.getScriptId();

  var url = 'https://script.googleapis.com/v1/projects/' + scriptID + '/content';
  var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();

  var options = {
    'method' : 'get',
    'headers' : {'Authorization':'Bearer '+  token},
    'muteHttpExceptions' : true
  };

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  var json = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());

  Logger.log(json.files[1].source);
  Logger.log(json.files[1].source.timeZone) //returns null instead of time zone

  var source = JSON.parse(json.files[1].source);
  Logger.log(source.timeZone); //this works

  //looking to modify JSON like below
  //json.files[1].source.timeZone = 'America/New_York';

  //then upload JSON to modify script
  /*
  var options = {
    'method' : 'put',
    'headers' : {'Authorization':'Bearer '+  token},
    'contentType' : 'application/json',
    'payload' : json
  };

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  */
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You want to change the version of installed library using Google Apps Script API.
- You have already been able to get and put values for Google Apps Script project using Google Apps Script API.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

#### Modification points:

- In order to change the version of library, please modify `json.files[1].source` parsed as a JSON object.
- In this case, `json.files[1].source` is required to put as the string type. So after the version was updated to the object parsed `json.files[1].source`, please set it to `json.files[1].source` as the string type.
- When you want to use the library by changing the version, please set `developmentMode` as `false`. By this, you can use each version.
- When you put the modified payload, please modify `'payload' : json` to `'payload' : JSON.stringify(json)`.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
function getScriptData() {
  var libraryId = "###";  // Please set the library ID you want to change the version.
  var updateVersion = "2";  // Please set the changed version. In this case, the version is changed to "2".

  var scriptID = ScriptApp.getScriptId();
  var url = 'https://script.googleapis.com/v1/projects/' + scriptID + '/content';
  var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
  var options = {
    'method' : 'get',
    'headers' : {'Authorization':'Bearer '+  token},
    'muteHttpExceptions' : true
  };
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  var json = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());

  // Here, json.files[].source is modified.
  json.files.forEach(function(file, i) {
    if (file.name == "appsscript") {
      var source = JSON.parse(file.source);
      if (source.hasOwnProperty("dependencies") && source.dependencies.hasOwnProperty("libraries")){
        source.dependencies.libraries = source.dependencies.libraries.map(function(e) {
          if (e.libraryId == libraryId) {
            e.version = updateVersion;
            e.developmentMode = false;
          }
          return e;
        });
        json.files[i].source = JSON.stringify(source, null, "  ");
      }
    }
  });

  // Modified json object is put to the Google Apps Script.
  var options = {
    'method' : 'put',
    'headers' : {'Authorization':'Bearer '+  token},
    'contentType' : 'application/json',
    'payload' : JSON.stringify(json)
  };
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  Logger.log(response)
}
```

#### Note:

- This is a simple modified script. So please modify this for your actual situation.

#### References:

- [Manifest structure](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/manifest)
- [Method: projects.updateContent](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/projects/updateContent)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: Tanaike, thank you so much for taking the time to provide such a robust solution.  It works perfectly for me.  You also taught me another feature I wasn’t aware of.  The replacer function used within the stringify method.  Thanks again.

Comment: @gries Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Comment: For others using this answer, which was very helpful, I just want to clarify: if you are trying to update a bound script from a standalone script, you need to change the scriptID variable to the id of that other, bound script (or write a for loop with an array of script id's). You can't leave it as the current file's id.