# Update gs files from script using API

Tags: google-apps-script, clasp

Can you please tell me if it is possible to change the contents of the gs files of the same project from the google app script. This is required to receive code updates.

I am looking for opportunities to use the API, similar to how google clasp does it.

How realistic is it to do this?

[UPDATE]

Try this code:

```
  var scriptID = ScriptApp.getScriptId();
  var url = 'https://script.googleapis.com/v1/projects/' + scriptID + '/content';
  var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
  var options = {
    'method' : 'get',
    'headers' : {'Authorization':'Bearer '+  token},
    'muteHttpExceptions' : true
  };
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  var json = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  Logger.log(json);
```

In Logger:

```
{error={details=[{domain=googleapis.com, @type=type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo, reason=ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE_INSUFFICIENT, metadata={service=script.googleapis.com, method=google.apps.script.management.v1.ProjectsService.GetContent}}], message=Request had insufficient authentication scopes., code=403.0, status=PERMISSION_DENIED}}
```

Comment: In your situation, how about using Google Apps Script API? For example, in order to update the script of Google Apps Script project, first, the script is retrieved using [Method: projects.getContent](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/projects/getContent), and modify the retrieved script, and then, the Google Apps Script project is updated by the modified script with [Method: projects.updateContent](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/projects/updateContent). This thread might be useful. https://stackoverflow.com/q/60674161

Comment: What @Tanaike mentioned is correct. I added his comment as a community wiki and added a bit more info to it so anyone can have this post for future references.

Comment: @Fernando Lara I would like to agree with your action.

Comment: I tried the code above but got an access error.

And according to the link [developers.google.com](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/projects/updateContent?hl=ru) everything works fine

Answer (score 1):

As [Tanaike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7108653/tanaike) mentioned, you can in fact edit gs files from Google Apps Script using the Google Apps Script API.

Actually Google Clasp does use the Google Apps Script API to make the exact same type of changes.

[image]

You can take the following request as an example using the method `projects.updateContent` to make a simple change in the `source` parameter. In addition to that, you need to make sure that the Google Apps Script API is enabled from your [Apps Script Settings](https://script.google.com/home/usersettings), and not only add the gs file you want to send in the request, but also the appsscript.json file from the manifest is required in the request.

```
{
  "files": [
    {
      "name": "appsscript",
      "type": "JSON",
      "source": "{\n  \"timeZone\": \"America/El_Salvador\",\n  \"dependencies\": {},\n  \"exceptionLogging\": \"STACKDRIVER\",\n  \"runtimeVersion\": \"V8\"\n}"
    },
    {
      "name": "Code",
      "type": "SERVER_JS",
      "source": "function myFunction() {\n  Logger.log(\"This is a test\");\n}\n",
      "functionSet": {
        "values": [
          {
            "name": "myFunction"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

#### References:

- [Method: projects.updateContent](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/projects/updateContent)
- [Clasp](https://github.com/google/clasp)

Comment: Thank you! Could you show an example of working code?